# php version of pythons if in

Tags: php

Python has the great: if sub-string in string, like this:

```
if "fox" in "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog":
   print True
```

Does does PHP have something equivalent to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) and [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
if(stripos("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog","fox")!==false)
   { echo 'True'; }
```

stripos and strpos return the position at which the match started, so you need to use strict comparison (=== or !==) to avoid a false negative when the needle is at pos. 0 in the haystack.

You may prefer [stristr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php), which just returns the matched string or boolean false.

[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) works about the same as `in` does in Python for lists and dictionaries, if you are also thinking beyond strings.

Comment: Thanks for the note about the strict comparison

Answer (score 2):

[strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways.  One is:

```
if(stristr('fox','The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog') !== FALSE){
...code
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php

stripos and others may be more efficient. See [PHP String Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)

Comment: its `===`|`!==` for type comparison its `==`|`!=` for value comparison, and `=` to assign

Answer (score 1):

There's three that I can think of: [substr](https://www.php.net/substr), [strpos](https://www.php.net/strpos), and [strstr](https://www.php.net/strstr). Each of those are case sensitive, and there are also case insensitive versions of those functions as well. PHP has a ridiculous number of string handling commands, so really just peruse the [string section of the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) until you see the one you want.